# SonarQube Plugin on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, sonarqube, sonarlint

i am getting the following error on running the sonarqube analysis in eclipse

```
Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain.execute(BatchLauncherMain.java:41)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain.main(BatchLauncherMain.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:98)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractPath.resolve(AbstractPath.java:53)
    at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputFile.path(DefaultInputFile.java:72)
    at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputFile.file(DefaultInputFile.java:64)
    at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.PathPattern$RelativePathPattern.match(PathPattern.java:101)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.filesystem.LanguageDetection.isCandidateForLanguage(LanguageDetection.java:124)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.filesystem.LanguageDetection.language(LanguageDetection.java:97)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.filesystem.InputFileBuilder.completeAndComputeMetadata(InputFileBuilder.java:100)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.filesystem.FileIndexer$1.call(FileIndexer.java:157)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.filesystem.FileIndexer$1.call(FileIndexer.java:154)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Please add more details: Eclipse version, plugin version, SonarQube server version.

Comment: eclipse version 4.4.0,plugin version 3.5, SonarQube server 5.1

Answer (score 0):

FYI, the Eclipse SonarQube plugin is deprecated and has been replaced by SonarLint for Eclipse : http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/.